# How can I protect my Town Hall 5 from level 7 players and higher?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I tried to protect my Town Hall and my village got annihilated easily. I keep getting 3 starred and a lot of people stole all of my loot. My Town Hall 5 is almost maxed out. I am out of loot, What can I do?

Comment: Pretty much nothing. If a TH7 player wants to wreck the base of a TH5 player, then they're going to wreck it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*When you mean level 7 players and higher, do you mean Town Hall level 7 and higher?*

If so, you don't have much of an option as TH7 troops are much stronger than TH5's max defense can provide.

I would recommend dropping trophies by intentionally losing matches and/or increasing your max defense levels by leveling up your Town Hall if you are having an issue with keeping loot.  Once you level up your Town Hall, that will unlock more and higher level defenses to protect your loot.

See: 
[Town Hall Differences](http://www.gamatrix.com/clash-of-clans/wiki#TownHall) or [Clash Defenses](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Defensive_Buildings)

Comment: The only other way I can think of to protect your base from being attacked is to keep the amount of stored resources you have low. Low available resources means less reward for attackers and less numerical loss of resources if someone decides to attack you anyway. But, this may be counterproductive for the current goals of the player who is trying to save resources while the town hall upgrades.